# How to code the log function in VBA right?

Tags: excel, vba

my prof gave us the exercise to code a function, which shows if your child is growing right or not. The only problem is that he didnt really explained us VBA. So everything I have come up with so far is all learnt on the net. Can you guys look over my function and maybe point out my failure(s) ? I know the logic should work but I think I make some failures with the syntax of VBA.

Thank you very much the code is beneath.

````
Dim months As Integer
Dim height As Double
Dim p1, p2, p3, p4 As Double
Dim message As String
childgroup = message
months = months / 100
p1 = 0
p2 = 0
p3 = 0
p4 = 0

p1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Log(months + 1, 20) + 0.3 / months
p2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Log(months + 1, 30) + 0.3 / months
p3 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Log(months + 1, 40) + 0.3 / months
p4 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Log(months + 1, 50) + 0.3 / months

If p2 <= height <= p1 Then message = "green"
ElseIf p3 <= height < p2 Then
message = "orange"
Else: message = "red"
End If

End Function```
````

Comment: Why did you think you made some errors? Does it return an error? How do you call this function? What values do you pass it? And where? Have a look at [ask] a question with a [mcve] and edit your question to make it more complete =)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/log-function

Comment: `If p2 <= height <= p1 ` doesn't do what you think it does.  You'll need `If ( p2 <= height) and (height <= p1 )`

Comment: `Dim p1, p2, p3, p4 As Double` is wrong too. Look at the types you get in a watch window

Answer (score 0):

what are the formula you want to check for? The current p1-p4 values don't make sense to me. An upgrade to your code, partially based on the comments below your post below.
Some basic remarks:

- add comments to your code, comments start with a single quote
- do give the variables some meaningful name, like "age_months" vs "months"

Hope this helps.

```
Sub test_this_function()

    Debug.Print growing_status(12, 0.8)
    Debug.Print growing_status(24, 0.8)

End Sub

Function growing_status(age_months As Integer, height_m As Double) As String

Dim p1 As Double, p2 As Double, p3 As Double, p4 As Double
Dim message As String

p1 = 0
p2 = 0
p3 = 0
p4 = 0

childgroup = message 'what does this do? seems without use
months_two = age_months / 100 'why this, months_two is now a double?

Debug.Print Application.WorksheetFunction.Log(age_months + 1, 40)

p1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Log(months_two + 1, 20) + 0.3 / months_two
p2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Log(months_two + 1, 30) + 0.3 / months_two
p3 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Log(months_two + 1, 40) + 0.3 / months_two
p4 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Log(months_two + 1, 50) + 0.3 / months_two

If p2 <= height_m And height_m <= p1 Then
    message = "green"
ElseIf p3 <= height_m And height_m < p2 Then
    message = "orange"
Else
    message = "red"
End If

growing_status = message

End Function
```